# bxslider hangs after clicking a link then going back - get eternal progress spinner

Tags: jquery, freeze, bxslider

Bxslider works great until I leave the page then go back to the page with the slider.
When I go back all I see is white space with a progress spinner for eternity.
The problem only happens in IE ... not Firefox or Chrome.  How can I fix?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/basic.css"/>
<script src="jquery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<link href="jquery/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
   auto: true,
   nextSelector: '#slider-next',
   prevSelector: '#slider-prev',
   nextText: 'Next →',
   prevText: '← Previous',
   slideWidth: 450,
   speed: 700,
   pause: 7000,
   responsive: false
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `$(window).load` instead of `$(document).ready`.